# Yahoo Maps Geocode

Tags: geocoding, yahoo-maps

How Do I work around a problem with the yahoo map geocode result set? The result set being returned is wrong. The city field contains the city, region and postal code. As seen below.

Is there a way to work around this issue without breaking scalability.

> -33.924320
>   151.187057
>   203 Coward St
>   MASCOT  NSW  2020
>   Australia   
>   AU

Answer (score 1):

The [Yahoo geoencoding](http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/rest/V1/geocode.html) returns usually an XML or a PHP serialized. By querying the encoding service I suppose you already have the address and you want to get the coordinates for your geoPoint. It is possible that you are feeding the maps engine with a wrong request.

If you think you found a bug you can send them an email, but I suggest you to check with other locations or to publish first here your code in order to spot the eventual errors.